# Dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows XP) - Error: No such device XXXXXXX

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

I am completely newbie on Linux. Some years ago I installed Windows XP and Ubuntu on my notebook, in a same HD, properly partitioned. Today I reinstalled Windows XP, but now I got this error message "Error: No such device XXXXXXXXX - Press any key to continue" when try to enter XP. Btw, I can enter XP after pressing a key.

Please, how can I fix it and remove this error message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described below, my first thought was not correct:

The combination of the words "years ago" and "Notebook" suggest the possibility that your cmos battery could be weak or dead and it may have simply lost its cmos settings.  I suggest you use whatever key is recommended to enter SETUP such as F2 on many brands, be sure to press SAVE SETTINGS when done even if you don't actually make any changes.

It turned out not to be the CMOS. Despite my suggestion the hard drive might be failing, which is not unusual after some years in an active laptop, the owner thinks the problem is related to GRUB, so I'm tacking on GRUB repair instructions below.

The easiest and most foolproof way to fix your grub is accomplished by opening [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), creating the self booting automated GRUB repair cd and booting to it.

Comment: You are right @gyropyge, it is an old noteebok, but CMOS battery is fine. Anyway I did what you suggested, but problem remains :( Any other tip? Thank you and HAPPY NEW YEAR!

Comment: My first thought was the hard drive, actually, just because netbooks tend to suffer more than desktops.  If you open "disk utility" (and if your hard drive supports SMART), you can read about what shape your hard drive is in.

Comment: I don't think it is a "hardware" problem. My bet it a GRUB problem... I researched about how to fix, but without sucess.

Comment: @Paruba, I have updated my answer to cover all the bases, INCLUDING GRUB REPAIR.  Personally I still think investigating the health of your hard drive as that is far more likely to fail on its own, but if you insist on trying to repair GRUB, please accept my near foolproof suggestion linked in my answer.

Comment: I forgot to say, dual-boot was working just fine few hours ago, before I formated and reinstalled Windows XP. That's the why I do not think it is a hardware problem. I will try your second tip. Thank you again!